# System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types

Tags: c#, oracle

I have an exception in my code. I have already tried to change my int64 to int32 but that doesn't change it.

In the database, the cells that represent "column_ID" have datatype NUMBER.

The problem is at line 7 in this code:

```
private void dataGridView_ArticleINVIA_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex <= (sender as DataGridView).Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        try
        {
            Int64 id_riga = Convert.ToInt64((sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["column_ID"].Value);
            //Exception thrown here:
            int id_macchina = Convert.ToInt32((sender as 
                DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["column_Machine"].Value);
            FormRecipeNote PopUpNote = new FormRecipeNote(id_macchina, 
                "MODIFICA", id_riga, 0);
            PopUpNote.ShowDialog(this);
            PopUpNote.Dispose();
         }
         catch (Exception Exc)
         {
             FormMain.loggerSoftwareClient.Trace(this.Name + " " + Exc);
         }
         //DataGrid_ArticleINVIA();
    }
}
```

the error is:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
   at System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ToInt64(Object value)
   at Software_Client.FormSendReceiveRecipe.dataGridView_ArticleINVIA_CellDoubleClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
```

Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: The exception is telling you exactly what you need to know - `Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["column_Machine"].Value` is `DbNull`, and you can't cast `DbNull` to any other type. Check if your `column_Machine` cell is `DbNull` before calling `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: You mean that i only need to check if the value is DbNull? and if it so? i checked on database the value and is not NULL

Comment: @Laxedur Correct, it's not `null`, it's `DBNull`.  The two are different.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you can call Dispose on an object, you should surround it with a using block:
`using (FormRecipeNote PopUpNote = new FormRecipeNote(id_macchina, 
                "MODIFICA", id_riga, 0))
{
            PopUpNote.ShowDialog(this);
 }`

Answer (score 10):

As the error message says, the value of the cell is `DBNull.Value` and it can't convert from that to whatever you want it to be (in this case a `long` or an `int`).  You need to check for `DBNull` before converting/casting the number:

```
Int64 id_riga = 0;
object value = (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["column_ID"].Value;
if(value != DBNull.Value) 
    id_riga = Convert.ToInt64(value);
```

Because this adds some annoying overhead, if you do this much you'll probably want to make a helper method that does it for you.

```
public static long? getLongFromDB(object value)
{
    if (value == DBNull.Value) return null;
    return Convert.ToInt64(value);
}
```

Then your code can be:

```
Int64 id_riga = getLongFromDB((sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["column_ID"].Value)
    .GetValueOrDefault();
```

Comment: @MSakherSawan By an entirely negligible amount.  Also, you assert it won't work (even though it will).

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the reply, tomorrow I will see if I can get with your code to solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

You can change the problematic line to :

```
int id_macchina = ((sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["column_Machine"].Value as int?).GetValueOrDefault();
```

This will give the default value of int (0) to the variable `id_macchina` if the value of the column `column_Machine` is null in the database (will be `DBNull` in C#)

Try this:

```
object aa = DBNull.Value;
int a = (aa as int?).GetValueOrDefault();
```

It will work! the value will be 0 if the column is `DBNull`.

*** EDIT ***

But try to use something else, this may hide some bugs, such as changing the data type, if the type is long and not int in the database, will always assign 0 to the variable, it happened with me in the past, thanks to @hvd to to indicate to that in his comment.

Comment: it's not a nullable `int`, it's using `DBNull` instead of `null`.

Comment: But this will solve the problem :) you are describing the cause of the problem and I am solving the problem!! why the donw-vote!

Comment: I didn't said that it is nullable, but my line will solve the problem, I have used nullable to use the safe casting (as).

Comment: Try this:
            object aa = DBNull.Value;

            int a = (aa as int?).GetValueOrDefault();

Comment: @svick Actually, technically it will work.  Since `DBNull` isn't of type `int` or `int?` the cast fails, and the result of `as` is that it returns `null` while an actual `int` is successfully cast.  However it's quite confusing as it gives the false impression that it won't work, and it isn't clear what it's really doing, so the readability suffers greatly.

Comment: @Servy Ah, you're right. I tried `DBNull.Value as int?`, which didn't work, but this is different (because the value is typed as `object`).

Comment: Thanx @Servy to your straightforwardness!!

Comment: @MSakherSawan You're right, it will work. But I agree with Servy that it is very confusing. Also, it might hide a bug: if the value is actually some other type, you want a loud error, not silently return `null`.

Comment: Once it's a common idiom, it stops being confusing. I've seen this used enough to not get confused by it, so +1 from me. The point about silently treating different types (say the server type changes, and you now get a `long`) as `null` is a valid point, though.

Comment: You are right @hvd , I will edit my answer to describe this :)

Comment: There is really no reason to go through `int?` (aka `Nullable<int>`) if you are just going to call GetValueOrDefault() on it. It's a simple exercise to write a nice & convenient extension method to do exactly the same thing, but with much more straightforward semantics. You can even go further in the extension method to do more error checking, etc for objects that are neither equal to DBNull nor convertible to the desired type. IMO these cases should not be silently ignored as they would be by calling `as int?` etc.

Comment: IMHO, this entire conversation about casting to `int?` and whether it will work and whether it is a good idea or not is completely off topic. This really does nothing for the OP who is simply trying to figure out why DBNull is showing up in the cell when the actual database value IS NOT NULL (at least as far as he can tell). So it might be more worthwhile to help him get to the bottom of his real issue rather than debating the best paradigm to use to detect & convert DBNulls. The question is WHY is the cell Null/DBNull in the first place, and how can the OP find the source of the bug.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused by some of your comments. Like for example, in your code the comment indicates that the line containing `ToInt32` is where the error occurs, but the error message clearly shows that the error is thrown from within `ToInt64`.

Also, you said that the value in the database is NOT null. If that is true, you would not get the DBNull value, so it may be worthwhile to expand your code a bit so that you can so you can place some breakpoints and inspect the values in the cells directly before trying to convert them.

I've posted some example code below that you can use, including a conversion helper function that you might find useful.

```
//--------- inside the try block of your event handler -----------//
        var row = (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex];
        object objId = row.Cells["column_ID"].Value;
        object objMachine = row.Cells["column_Machine"].Value;
        // place a breakpoint on the line below, 
                    // so you can inspect the "obj..." values above to see
                    // if they are DBNull or not.

        var id_riga = objId.FromDb<Int64>();
        var id_macchina = objMachine.FromDb<Int32>();
//-----------continue your code here---------//

//----outside the form class, possibly in a separate file -----/
static class DbObjectExtensions {
    public static T FromDb<T>(this object dbObj, T defaultValueIfNull = default(T)) where T : IConvertible {
        if (Convert.IsDBNull(dbObj))
            return defaultValueIfNull;
        if (dbObj is T)
            return (T)dbObj;
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(dbObj, typeof(T));
    }
}
```

I also want to clear up a comment I saw above that said "...it's not null, it's DBNull. The two are different". That statement is true in general, in C#, however it's actually misleading in the context it was written. It was written in response to the previous comment that said "[I] checked on database the value and is not NULL". For clarification, a NULL in a database field IS represented by DBNull in most .Net database providers. So in fact, a NULL value in the database IS usually the same as DBNull in C#. So if the OP is correct in saying that the database value is NOT NULL, then it *does* follow that the cell value should not be DBNull.

Of course it is still true that `null` is not the same as `DBNull`, so checking to see if an object is null does not determine whether it is DBNull or not, (but that is not what the OP said).

As a final note, the extension method I wrote, `FromDB`, includes an optional parameter for a default return value in the case that the object passed is DBNull.
This can be used as follows:

```
//assuming -1 isn't a valid 
var id_riga = objId.FromDb<Int64>(-1); id
if (id_riga == -1) { /*handle case for null db value*/ }
```

Depending on your own personal preferences the above paradigm might be easier to understand than the Nullable version described in other answers.