# is it possible to change the position of the blank row at the end of the datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

I want to allow user to add rows but the blank row must be in he first position to let the user enter data without scroll down each time to insert a new row ?!

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDh6o.png]

This is how I add the rows in the datagridview :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Parc_Automobile
{
    public class SqlHelper
    {
        private const string ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=KIM;Initial Catalog=TestingBlank;Integrated Security=True";

        private readonly DataGridView _dgv;
        private BindingSource _bindingSource;
        private DataTable _dataTable;
        private string _selectQueryString;
        private SqlConnection _sqlConnection;
        private SqlDataAdapter _sqlDataAdapter;

        protected SqlHelper(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            _dgv = dgv;
        }

        //display a table in datagridview
        public void ShowTable(String tableName)
        {
            _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            _sqlConnection.Open();

            _selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
            _sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(_selectQueryString, _sqlConnection);
            var sqlCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(_sqlDataAdapter);
            _dataTable = new DataTable();
            _sqlDataAdapter.Fill(_dataTable);
            _bindingSource = new BindingSource {DataSource = _dataTable};

            var tempRow = this._dataTable.NewRow();
            this._dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(tempRow, 0);

            _dgv.DataSource = _bindingSource;
            _sqlConnection.Close();
        }

        //Search In datagridview using input of users
        public void SearchTable(String SearchText, String columnNameToSearch, int type)
        {
            try
            {
                var filterBuilder = "";
                switch (type)
                {
                    case TEXT_COLUMN:
                        filterBuilder = columnNameToSearch + " LIKE '" + SearchText + "%'";
                        break;

                    case NUMERIC_COLUMN:
                        filterBuilder = columnNameToSearch + " = '" + SearchText + "'";
                        break;
                }
                var bs = new BindingSource
                {
                    DataSource = _dgv.DataSource,
                    Filter = filterBuilder
                };
                _dgv.DataSource = bs;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // ignored
            }
        }

        public void DeleteRow()
        {
            if (_dgv.CurrentRow != null) _dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(_dgv.CurrentRow.Index);
            _sqlDataAdapter.Update(_dataTable);
        }

        public void SaveChanges(Label label)
        {
            try
            {
                _sqlDataAdapter.Update(_dataTable);
                label.Text = "Changement a été effectué avec succès.";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("" + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new row use the `Insert` method instead of `Add`. `Insert` allows to specify the index for the new row. Set the index to `0`:

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0,new DataGridViewRow());
```

**EDIT I**

Adjusting the answer to your comment: if you are using a binding to a data source you have to create a new row using the data source. Then you insert it at specified position. Let's say that you have `myDataSet` data source with a `Log` table in it. This code will create a new row and insert it as the first row:

```
var tempRow = this.myDataSet.Log.NewRow();
this.myDataSet.Log.Rows.InsertAt(tempRow, 0);
```

Your `DataGridView` will be updated appropriately.

**EDIT II**

You will get exception if you try, for instance, to assign data type different than a column type in your table. Say the `ID` column is int but you try to add `string`. To handle data errors you have to handle the `DataError` event. Below an example using your code.

```
protected SqlHelper(DataGridView dgv)
{
    _dgv = dgv;
    _dgv.DataError += _dgv_DataError;
}

void _dgv_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Incorrect data: {0}", e.Exception.Message) );
        e.Cancel = false;

        // handle the exception
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added this code in the constructor of the form but I get an error : Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DataGridView's rows collection when the control is data-bound.

Comment: In that case you have to create the row on your data source and insert the new row with specified position on that data row. I'll add an edit in a minute.

Comment: sorry to disturb you I tried to apply your new answer but I didn't use dataset in my code , could you help me I added in the question how I display the rows sorry I'm an absolute beginner

Comment: Actually you do. You have your `sqlConnection` and `dataTable`. I cannot test it right now but I would say that when adding a new row you have to open the connection and use the `dataTable` to create a row as in my example.

Comment: I just test it in the code right now , the row appears blank in the top but there is no "*" that mean user can enter data , I tried enter data but I got : Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

Comment: Sounds like there is an issue with converting data type. Check this suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14058791/3330348

Comment: I'll give up my idea of make the blank row in the first position , thank you fo r the solution and sorry disturbing you !

Comment: In case you prefer to return to this issue I try to spend some time this afternoon anyway, though not sooner than in 8 hours. Can you please add a code for your current method that adds the row.

Comment: okay ! I copied all the class I use in my program , ShowTable is the method that adds the row and display them in datagrid , and I have saveChange to save what users change in the datagrid to database.